# Is there any way to give c# enums a "range" of allowed values?

Tags: c#, enums

Say I have an enum like the following, where I want the numbering to start at 1000.

```
public enum Fruits : uint
{
    Apple = 1000,
    Orange = 1001,
    Strawberry = 1002,
    Banana = 1003,
    Blueberry = 1004,
}
```

Assigning each `Fruit` a number is tedious and hard to read, not to mention awkward if I have 20+ `Fruit`s and might want to reorder them or add/remove a `Fruit`. Is there any kind of syntax like the following?

```
public enum Fruits : uint where value >= 1000
{
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Strawberry,
    Banana,
    Blueberry,
}
```

Comment: Set `1000` only to first fruit, others fruits will have value incremented by 1

Comment: Just define the value for your first element (Apple), and you are set. All further elements get values that will be incremented by one. The documentation for `enum` will tell you this, too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum. Or here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types  Documentation is an amazing thing... ;-)

Comment: Note that even if you assign values, _technically_ you can pass any integer as an `enum`; it just won't correspond to your defined values. That's becasue internally the enum is just compiled to a native type (usually `int`). Meaning if you have a function that accepts a `Fruit` parameter, you could pass any value to it; it doesn't have to be one of your defined values.

Comment: as soon as you start to store values from that enum somewhere (files, a database, ...) and need to maintain a certain degree of version compatibility, you will find that explicitely numbering them and never change a number once assigned is what you want.

Comment: Standard trick to get a range that's useful for validation is to add an extra member, Last = Blueberry.  And perhaps you want First = Apple in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [are ranges possible with enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778487/are-ranges-possible-with-enums)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Fabio stated in a comment, enum auto-values are based off the value of the previous enum, so the following code snippets compile identically:

```
public enum Fruits : uint
{
    Apple = 1000,
    Orange = 1001,
    Strawberry = 1002,
    Banana = 1003,
    Blueberry = 1004,
}
```

---

```
public enum Fruits : uint
{
    Apple = 1000,
    Orange,
    Strawberry,
    Banana,
    Blueberry,
}
```

Thank you @Fabio!